# Can i split a message.content and just print a few informations out it? discord.py

Tags: python, twitter, discord, filtering, discord.py

Hey i made a twitter monitor, but it just gives me this:

```
{
  "created_at": "Tue Sep 01 20:28:39 +0000 2020",
  "id": 1300893351877672960,
  "id_str": "1300893351877672960",
  "text": "Test",
  "source": "\u003ca href="
  https: //mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow"\u003eTwitter Web App\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1281984032167927808,"id_str":"1281984032167927808","name":"","screen_name":"","locati
}
```

What can i do to get filtered text with this information: `created at`, `screen_name` and `text`

Comment: How is this related to discord? I couldn't understand what you want to do with discord and how did you get this output?

Comment: that the message gets send in a discord server

Comment: Where did you get this output?

Answer (score 1):

If you're output looks like that you can just do this:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    data = {
        "created_at": "Tue Sep 01 20:28:39 +0000 2020",
        "id": 1300893351877672960,
        "id_str": "1300893351877672960",
        "text": "Test"
    }

    print(data['created_at'])
    print(data['text'])
```

I don't have your data source so i stored it in a variable.

Output:

```
Tue Sep 01 20:28:39 +0000 2020
Test
```

Comment: Jonas, just be sure that your variable for your data that you receive is set to data.